# TypeScript Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: javascript, typescript, state, store, lit

I'm trying to implement app state management with [litState](https://github.com/gitaarik/lit-state) for a TypeScript project but get an error when I try to use the `counter` state in the component `Cannot assign to read only property 'counter' of object '#<DemoState>'     at new DemoState (demo-state.js:11:22)`

Like their example [HERE](https://gitaarik.github.io/lit-state/build/#intro-page/) I have declared `my-state.js` with a counter

```
import { LitState, stateVar } from 'lit-element-state';

class MyState extends LitState {
    @stateVar() counter = 0;
}

export const myState = new MyState();
```

I'm trying to use `observeState()` in the `component.js`

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
import { observeState } from 'lit-element-state';
import { demoState } from './demo-state.js';

export class MyClass extends observeState(LitElement) {
  render() {
    console.log('STATE: ', demoState.counter);
    return html`<h1>MyClass View</h1>`;
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there anything I can do in typescript to mediate the error above?

Please let me know if I can provide additional details.

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: My apologies, it's been a while since I've posted on here. I had included the link to the example but also added the actual content for visual. Hope that helps! @David

Comment: This library has 260 downloads and was last updated 2 years ago I would just assume that it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the litState library doesn't play very well with TS - I had to switch up and use [lit-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-store/v/1.2.3)

Works like a charm!